# matching column in one sheet to column in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to populate cells in column A of Sheet "Alpha" by comparing all the rows in column C in sheet "Alpha" with column C in sheet "Beta". I want to populate cells such that if for each row in sheet "alpha" if the value in that row in column C matches with *any* of the cell values in sheet "beta"'s column C then there will be an X in Column A of sheet "alpha". If there is no match, then do not fill the cell.
For example
Say row 2 in column C for sheet "alpha" is "dog", if any cells in sheet "Beta"'s column C match "dog" then row 2 in column A of sheet "alpha" will have an "X" in it.

Can this be done without VBA using just the match function to look at different sheets?

Specific output
sheet alpha

```
+---+--+---------+
| X |  | dog     |
+===+==+=========+
|   |  | cat     |
+---+--+---------+
| x |  | dolphin |
+---+--+---------+
```

Sheet beta

```
+--+--+-----------+
|  |  | dolphin   |
+==+==+===========+
|  |  | cappybara |
+--+--+-----------+
|  |  | dog       |
+--+--+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `IF`, `ISNA` and `MATCH` functions. Adapt the formula below. Replace the ranges to suit your data.

```
=IF(IFNA(MATCH(C1,Beta!$C$1:$C$3,0),0)>0,"X","")
```

- MATCH(C1,Beta!$C$1:$C$3,0): checks whether the criteria from sheet alpha exists in sheet beta.
- IFNA(MATCH(C1,Beta!$C$1:$C$3,0),0): This is for error handling. If the criteria exists, MATCH function returns a number greater than 0. If the criteria does not exist, `#NA` is returned. Using `ISNA` allows to return `0` instead of `#NA`.
- IF(IFNA(MATCH(C1,Beta!$C$1:$C$3,0),0)>0,"X",""): checks if the returned number is greater than 0 or not. If true, `x` is shown. If not, an empty string is shown on the cell.

[image]

Comment: this refers to column not a separate sheet though. The sheet is a different tab in excel.

Comment: @WritLoax You must adapt the formula.

Comment: Is there a way to reference formulas in another sheet? Can you post a link that shows how to do that? I am new to excel

Comment: @WritLoax I have edited the answer. `Beta` here is the name of the other sheet. In Excel to reference a sheet in a formula, you put the sheet name followed by `!`.

Comment: ah interesting! One other question, does MATCH use exact text matching or if it had "DOGCAT" would it still think this is a "match" with "dog"

Comment: @WritLoax The second argument here for MATCH is 0 which means exact match. Thus, it will only find dog not dogcat. This argument can be changed to -1 or 1 to find smallest or greatest values. The data must be ordered either ascending or descending (when using 1 or -1). You can learn about the MATCH function [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a). If your question has been answered successfully, please mark the answer as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).